# C++: Convert std::string to UINT64

Tags: c++, string, uint64

I need to convert a (decimal, if it matters) string representation of a number input from a text file to a UINT64 to pass to my data object.

```
    size_t startpos = num.find_first_not_of(" ");
    size_t endpos = num.find_last_not_of(" ");
    num = num.substr(startpos, endpos-startpos+1);
    UINT64 input;
    //convert num to input required here
```

Is there any way to convert an std::string to a UINT64 in a similar way to atoi()?

Thanks!

Edit:
Working code below.

```
size_t startpos = num.find_first_not_of(" ");
size_t endpos = num.find_last_not_of(" ");
num = num.substr(startpos, endpos-startpos+1);
UINT64 input; //= std::strtoull(num.cstr(), NULL, 0);

std::istringstream stream (num);
stream >> input;
```

Comment: Saving a decimal in a uint64?

Comment: It's for a project I'm working on using existing structures. That's just the structure of the object in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two ways to do this:

1. Construct a `std::istringstream`, and use our old friend, the `>>` operator.
2. Just convert it yourself. Parse all the digits, one at a time, converting them to a single integer. This is a very good exercise. And since this is an unsigned value, there isn't even a negative number to worry about. I would think that this would be a standard homework assignment in any introductory computer science class. At least it was, back in my days.

Comment: The istringstream method worked for me. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4):

Use [strtoull](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) or [_strtoui64()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/85zk715d.aspx).
Example:

```
std::string s = "1123.45";
__int64 n = std::strtoull(s.c_str(),NULL,0);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to search how I can get the pointers to the beginning and end of the std::string, but havn't found anything yet. Do you know how I can get these?

Comment: @IpqD I have updated the answer. Regarding the string, there are: [string.begin()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/begin/) and [string.end()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/end/) iterators.

Comment: Thanks again :). I included the <cstdlib>  library, but my project seems to say that std has no member "strtoull". Would you know if this is something I have done wrong?

Also, is there a difference between __int64 and UINT64?

Comment: `uint64_t` is the standard fixed length 64 bit unsigned integer type. It is an optional part of the C standard, defined in `<stdint.h>`, in C++ therefore in `<cstdint>`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [stoull](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoull/):

```
char s[25] = "12345678901234567890"; // or: string s = "12345678901234567890";
uint64_t a = stoull(s);
```